# Elementor querying posts doesn't work on a single post

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, elementor

So I have a single post template made with Elementor Pro. I am using some extra plugins (like Elementor Extras) to enable infinite scroll functionality on the post template.

The problem comes in when I try to implement this infinite scroll on the post template. It just fails to load next posts - instead on infinite scroll event it returns me the same posts that were displayed previously.

For some peculiar reason the infinite scroll thing works perfectly on pages, like "Blog" or "About" page. But it doesn't work on singular posts. I have a vague suspicion that this is due to Wordpress default posts querying mechanism which is set to work on pages but not posts. This is where my knowledge ends and I don't know how to fix it so that proper querying would also work on singular posts.